# Directory stack order discrepancy in zsh

Tags: zsh, directory, autocomplete, cd-command

I am working on Zsh 5.0.2 (latest stable version), and I noticed that:

```
dirs -v
```

and

```
cd -<TAB>
```

show a **different** list of directories (or at least directories in different order).

Moreover, it seems as if `cd -` shows oldest directories at the top, with the more recent directories at the bottom (exactly the opposite of what I want)

Why are these lists different, and how can I change the options of these lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are moving from the right(to left) of the directory stack when using `-`. where as `dirs -v` prints the directory stack,in a list, from the left(to right). If you were to `cd +<TAB>` the completion would show in the same order as `dirs -v`. Using `dirs` without options, would give a more accurate visual representation of the stack and how you are rotating it with pushd & popd. If the `pushd_minus` option is set, the context of `-` and `+` are swapped.
`man zshbuiltins` and look for pushd for more information.